# How to fill between two different words using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

If I have a dataframe like this:

```
        A
 0  Ascent
 1   NaN
 2   NaN
 3  Descent
 4   NaN
 5  Ascent
```

How do I fill between words such that nan values between 'Ascent' and 'Descent' get filled with 'Above' and nan values between 'Descent' and 'Ascent' get filled with 'Below'. Such that I get a Pandas Data Frame like this:

```
        A
 0  'Ascent'
 1   'Above'
 2   'Above'
 3  'Descent'
 4   'Below'
 5  'Ascent'
```

Comment: can you have two ascents next to each other or two descents with NaN in-between ?

Comment: That could be a potential case. Didn't think of that

Comment: how do you want to handle those cases?

Answer (score 5):

I decided to have a little fun with `fillna` and `map`:

```
df

         A
0   Ascent
1      NaN
2      NaN
3  Descent
4      NaN
5   Ascent

df['A'].fillna(df['A'].ffill().map({'Ascent':'Above', 'Descent': 'Below'}))
# Identical solution, different order of method calls,
# df['A'].fillna(df['A'].map({'Ascent':'Above', 'Descent': 'Below'}).ffill())

0     Ascent
1      Above
2      Above
3    Descent
4      Below
5     Ascent
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: you are really fast! My respect!

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf It's practice, my friend!

Comment: @coldspeed nice!